# Updated alternative to jquery-resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

This used to be useful, [jQuery resize event](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-resize), in doing things like,

```
$(selector).on('resize', function() { .. });
```

but it has not been updated for a long time (last commit since 2010), and it doesn't quite work well in certain situations (it is for jQuery 1.4)

Is there an updated alternative for doing the above?

Comment: How updated do you need it to be? (What jQuery version and/or last commit since x)?

Answer (score 1):

[Jquery Mutate](http://www.jqui.net/jquery-projects/jquery-mutate-official/) is a plugin that should work. It's a bit more general purpose and fires events whenever the selection is mutated in any way.

If that doesn't work, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172821/detecting-when-a-divs-height-changes-using-jquery) might be able to help. Lots of useful answers there.